# Script to activate "Enter Time Machine"

Tags: macos, time-machine

I'm trying to get rid of the Time Machine icon in the menubar. Is there a way activate "Enter Time Machine" using a script or something along those lines? I know that we have `tmutil`, but it can not activate the main Time Machine view to restore files from.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just open **/Applications/Time Machine.app**